# How to send service bus message to deadletter queue in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, servicebus, dead-letter

How can I send message to deadletter queue?

```
serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage(MESSAGE_QUEUE, {isPeekLock: true}, (error, message) => {
    ...... // want to put message to deadletter queue if there is exception
    serviceBusService.deleteMessage(message, error => {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly, you'd want to rely on the system to decide when to move a message to DLQ and make it the messaging engine's responsibility as much as possible (and not explicitly put a message on DLQ.) It also appears that the guidance in this scenario was provided via documentation here: [How to handle application crashes and unreadable messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-nodejs-how-to-use-queues#how-to-handle-application-crashes-and-unreadable-messages)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using the older `azure-sb` package that relies on the HTTP REST apis. If you instead use the newer `@azure/service-bus` package which uses the faster AMQP implementation, there is a `deadletter()` method on the message you receive that you can use to send the message to the dead letter queue.